# Levenberg-Marquardt - What is preferable (A + mu.I) or (A + mu.diag[A])?

Tags: numerical-optimization

The step size is computed by solving

(A + mu I) h = -g

I could find in some literature that one can compute the step size by solving

(A + mu A') h = -g
where, A' = diagonal(A)

It is said that this is helpful for error valley problems, where the error surface at minima is flat and long.
I am not able to decide whether the diagonal(A) should be used in general for all cases, or the identity matrix I is more appropriate.

Comment: I guess Numerical Recipes has the (A + mu.diag[A]) implementation.

Comment: You may find [scicomp.se] a better site for such specialized questions.

Comment: Thanks. But if someone can answer, please do!